# installing grpc extension for php on ubuntu failed

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, grpc, pecl

```
command: sudo pecl install grpc
```

I tried installing grpc extension for php on ubuntu with the above command. The installation started then got stuck at some point, after which, it failed and outputted this error:

> g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
> compilation terminated.
> make: *** [Makefile:1428: src/core/ext/xds/xds_server_config_fetcher.lo] Error 1
>
> ERROR: `make' failed

how do i resolve this ?

Comment: It's far from clear what you even did, please extract a [mcve] to include in a description. However, this might be the topic for a bug report, rather than a SO question. Did you check the according bugtrackers, btw.?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i ran this command, sudo pecl install grpc - to install the grpc php extension. Installation started, got stuck at a point, then failed and output the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Resized the droplet, from 1gb to 4gb, and it worked; build completed.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Yep, `Killed` generally means you've run out of memory.